# How to bind state located in a parent component to a reusable selectInput component in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component called SelectInput.vue which takes an array of options for the select input, and a parent component in which this component is rendered. The parent component contains the user state that I want to be binded to the SelectInput component, and more specifically to the favoriteColor property. How do I do that?

Home.vue

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import SelectInput from './SelectInput.vue';

    const user = ref({
        name: '',
        favoriteColor: '',
    })

    const selectOptions = ref(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'white', 'black'])

</script>

<template>
    <div class="user-input-container">
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Favorite Color</p>
            <SelectInput :selectOptions="selectOptions" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

SelectInput.vue

```
<script setup>
    defineProps({
        selectOptions: Array,
    })
</script>

<template>
    <select>
        <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
        <option v-for="selectOption in selectOptions" v-bind:key="selectOption">{{ selectOption }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) is for. Assign your ref value to v-model, then the child component will need to accept it as a prop and emit any changes to the parent.

**Parent component**

```html
<SelectInput v-model="user.favoriteColor" />
```

**Child component**

```html
<select :value="modelValue" @change="updateModel">
```

```js
defineProps({ modelValue: String })
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

function updateModel(e) {
    emit('update:modelValue', e.target.value)
}
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9U8FO3DAQ/ZWRLwFpNzlwSwMqRVSiUltUql6aHkwyWQyOHdlOAK3y7x3b2d1kQeQSe/zmzcyz35Zddl069MhyVtjKiM6BRdd3F6UC+kTbaeNgCwYbGKExuoWE4MmnxfkdSqzcjep6N2HSbBbzBXxGzKm0sg56iwbOPe/JNsb9p3iLOSTJ6hBq+KCNcHilpTazs/F0SWhDvZ+dE7SdmP8mButkBcnGICq/uJfUCv2fH4gyBnj1lPwLZEUWJaDhaeOw7SR3OElR1GKASnJrz0vmu18LP9uaqjsuFJqSTcgP0AtMwHUXX6cBIUxYZDvt95C5usO61TXKiTRdiFMyyBcqEGqxJ0B2TE59XrylymG7DVe0DMM4FpnPmA062+/WRbbXjq2YsyRRIzbpo9WK3lm47pJVuu2ERLPvjWpGmpJxKfXztxBzpsfpxinnAaund+KP9sXHSnZrkJoesGT7M8fNBkl4f3x99wNfaL0/JDF7SegPDn+h1bL3PUbYl17V1PYMF7q9CU4QavPbXr84VHY3lG/UI8eALxl54eqD0Q/tnqVnIa9UI6l4ZKe3fjWRocaGHuOt0Z0lY01B/y1eQg6XxvDX1RwQHtYfTgbJ4c4ZGmV3SlabVtFq2ApHDoulrmljyWl9V9OF5wcWbypK26U2vap8bYjA7x53gqc0+awHz3zyDtUKMI3KpIMP7Bsa/eLg26nezLsTrojjQx7SyRgHcnLF5+qBq40Pz5rzXp21VuggHdTC8nuJNeyYCHcrkVucJAatsMgi+l2GYd1oc+RNEGp5Q9TVsL4Xqs6f8PUITBXJnot0b8yjkqRKQITA3JLjf4OS9hE=)